# zoho remote api normal form server side code

Tags: zoho

I am using zoho remote api for normal form, but i get error whenever i try to save my document Please help me to correct my code that is given below
i need help to save my document. every time i save the document get the error "unable post the content"

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" target="_blank" action="https://sheet.zoho.com/remotedoc.im" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="http://example.com/demo1/test.csv" name="url">
<input type="hidden" value="**********" name="apikey">
<input type="hidden" value="editor" name="output">
<input type="hidden" value="normaledit" name="mode">
<input type="hidden" value="test.csv" name="filename">
<input type="hidden" value="en" name="lang">
<input type="hidden" value="12345678" name="id">
<input type="hidden" value="csv" name="format">
<input type="hidden" value="save.php" name="saveurl">
<input c type="submit" value="Details" name="submit">
</form>


<?php

$filepath = '/home/spatials/public_html/demo1/'.$_FILES['content']['name'];

$tmp_filename = $_FILES['content']['tmp_name']; 

$upload_status = move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename, $filepath); 

?>
```

Pleas correct my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong Save URL:

```
<input type="hidden" value="php/save.php" name="saveurl" />
```

Correct Save URL:

```
<input type="hidden" name="saveurl" value="http://example.com/demo1/save.php" />
```

WIKI page link for reference: https://apihelp.wiki.zoho.com/Save-Document.html